# How to emit an event on application close using socket.io

Tags: javascript, react-hooks, socket.io, socket.io-client

I am trying emit an event while user closes the tab and for this I am emitting an event on unmount of a component ( which is nested inside a `Main` component) :

Emitting an event `REMOVE_SOCKETS` inside the cleanup function of `useEffect` unfortuantley doesn't trigger the event listener on the server side. I want to pass some paramertes like url, uid to know at which page/path the user closed the tab.

```
  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      debugger;
      if (socket) {
        socket.emit('REMOVE_SOCKETS', {
          url:  window.location.href,
        });
        socket.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, []);
```

on express server side:

```
s.on('REMOVE_SOCKETS', () => {
   // doing some application logic
})
```

I kept `debugger` statement to check if the `dev tools` in Chrome browser pauses instead of the closing of tab while unmounting the component but that didn't happen.

I searched in various answers of the similar question that to emit an event inside the `disconnect` event listner on server side as soon as we detect disconnect event like the following :

```
s.on('disconnect', () => {
   s.emit('DISCONNECT_ACK_TO_CLIENT') // which is not needed in my case
} )
```

but in my case the client will no longer be available and also there is nothing I want to do by emitting event inside disconnect.

Also is there a way I can differetiate tab close and refresh, so that I can emit `REMOVE_SOCEKTS` only on tab close not on tab refresh ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, it is not possible to do much when the tab is being closed by the user. And this is on purpose. Otherwise, the user won't be able to close malicious tabs. Event if that was possible, it would still not be reliable - consider killing the browser using task manager for example.

One common solution would be to listen for the "close" event on the *server* side, and do whatever is needed. This should be complemented with ping/pong messages, in case the socket dies unexpectedly, to track the connection state.